# What is the Use of user32.dll in VB Application?

Tags: winapi, vb6, vb6-migration

In our we have used the user32.dll and passing the value of hWnd.So I would like to know what is the use of this User32.dll and passing the value hWnd?

They are setting this Values

```
SetProp hwnd, "PrevWndProc", SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WindowProc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User32 is a library that manages all windows on your desktop. The hwnd parameter is a handle that identifies your window in the system

Comment: Thanks for your information .Here I have two function calling based on some condition 1. "SetProp" 2. "SetWindowLong" 3. "RemoveProp". Can you elobrate this more?

Comment: I played with VB very-very long time ago, so i can't read the syntax completely but it definitely calls SetWindowLong to alter WindowProc of this window. WindowProc is a message handler that serves  all messages sent to the window.

Answer (score 7):

It uses the `SetProp` Windows API function which associates a value with the window identified by the handle in the variable `hwnd`.

That fragment is used to store the address of the original *window procedure* (returned by `SetWindowLong`) whilst simultaneously replacing (subclassing) it with a VB6 procedure (called `WindowProc`), usually in order to interact with messages sent to the window.

A subsequent `SetWindowLong` with a lookup of the previously stored `hwnd` with `GetProp` restores the original windows procedure, followed by a `RemoveProp` to tidy up.

Comment: +1 @jai look inside WindowProc to see which windows messages it is handling & what it does so that you know what it is doing. Subclassing is an advanced way to extend the features of standard VB6 controls and forms.