# VB6 - reading from keyboard in an ActiveX DLL

Tags: dll, vb6, hid

I have an ActiveX DLL which currently reads from a serial port. Now I want it to accept input from a USB device.

The USB device functions as a standard Human Interface Device. That is to say, if I open Notepad then the device's output will appear in Notepad as if it were typed on a keyboard.

Normally, I would capture Key Up/Down events, but I think that I need a form for that and my DLL does not have a form.

How can I capture that input?

---

[Update] I found this http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/anyone-know-how-read-keyboard-input-within-an-activex-dll-help-7934442.html# which claims to do it, but the code there won't work as is uses the `AddressOf` operator, which can only be used in a .BAS file, so not in an DLL .CLS

I am not even sure if I am looking for a system wide hook or application specific.

Hmmm, http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=77216  says "You can't implement a global WH_KEYBOARD hook in VB - it requires a standard (non ActiveX dll) as it has to be loaded into the address space of all the running applications."

---

[Upper date] So, maybe I can a form, make it 1x1 pixel and invisible and have a function `GetTheData` which shows the form modally and collects and returns the data - either getting keyboard input at form level or into a (n invisible) control then closes the form returning the input.

Would that work? If anyone posts a working example I will award a bounty (I would prefer that the form not be visible on the task bar and have no close button; the user should not be aware of it, or able to close it, it should close itself when it receives enough input from the USB attached HDI).

Comment: You can have .bas modules in an ActiveX DLL too, not only .cls class modules. You can have .frm form modules too.

Comment: @wqw, I am new to VB, can you please post an answer with some more help (and see my updated question)? Thanks

Comment: I am constantly amazed at the number of people who say they are new to VB6. I mean, it hasn't be sold by Microsoft since about 2001! Mawg - where did you get your copy? I wouldn't mind buying one for old times' sake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RegisterRawInputDevices` to monitor HID devices' input but this requires a window to listen for `WM_INPUT` message which means subclassing the window.

Here is a working sample project: [UsbBarcodeSanner.zip](http://dl.unicontsoft.com/upload/UsbBarcodeSanner.zip)

Comment: Thanks +1 for posting. I will check your code & award the answer if ir woks. I Hope that I can make the window (form?) invisible, with no controls and 1x1 pixel. If not, I guess it can just say "reading data", but the serial post version doesn't have a window & I don't want to confuse the users. I was wondering if I could read from `stdin` (yup, I do know that's a Unix/Linux thing) or maybe `ShellExecute` something.  Btw, does your window had to be shown modally to be sure to get the input?

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear to me how to use this with an ActiveX DLL. Probably because I am new to VB6.

Comment: The sample is not an ActiveX DLL (I think; maybe I am missing the point). I can read from keyboard in a standard .EXE, but I need an ActiveX DLL

Comment: Implementing reading from keyboard is no different in AxDLL than in StdEXE. The sample is hooking a HID device (the USB scanner), intercepts its input and invokes a callback function with the complete barcode. It's not using `KeyDown` events.

Comment: +1 @vqw Ok, I will try to figure out the relevant bits of your code, but I am a VB6 noonbie. As I said, it seems powerful & flexible and I am not sure that I need all of it. Thanks, if I get it to work, you get the bonus.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have better option,

using uesr32.dll you can do this task easily,

refer this [link](http://www.ex-designz.net/apidetail.asp?api_id=143)

you will be able to use this function

`Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer`

This dll handles anything you want for user in windows.. refer [Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513138/what-is-the-use-of-user32-dll-in-vb-application)

I hope this will help..

Comment: +1 and thank you, it is not exactly what I want, but it is useful to know. Thanks

Comment: In that case I think you are handling some hardware using USB? or want a Key-stroke reader? or something else..

Comment: in case of hardware you can use USB to serial Bridge(Virtual) that is available in most of the mobile data Connectivity solutions(except android).. here is one example of driver refer this link http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/usb_keyboard.html that should help :) Or use `WINUSB` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174(v=vs.85).aspx that is a great work by windows it self..